# attachments are coming in allure-results folder but not displaying in allure report

Tags: selenium, testng, reporting, attachment, allure

while running test attachments are generated in allure-reports but not displaying in allure report

[this is allure report folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aPMp.png)
[here is method to take screenchot please refer allurecapture method, i have tried it without annotation also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G49I1.png) 
[this my report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgqfA.png)

[here i am calling the method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW3Zh.png)

i have tried to capture screenshot and add it to allure report. i have created static allurecapture() method in utility package and caliing it in ontestsuccess() method.

attachments are there in allure-reports folder but not coming in allure report. sometimes it comes but mostly not.

i have tried with only annotation.

```
@Attachment
    public static byte[] allurescreencapture(String screenshotname) {
        return ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the attachments are not generated? Normally the attachment is collapsed and you have to click on the component to expand and see the image.  Its not very user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue. Found an issue in github https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/issues/784 .

Downgrading dependency versions worked for me.

```
<aspectj.version>1.9.5</aspectj.version>
<allure-testng.version>2.15.0</allure-testng.version>
<testng.version>7.4.0</testng.version>
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion mate. But I am getting same issue again. i even tried with all versions you provided.